# SharePoint 2007 not sending Emails

Tags: 2007, workflow

I have created a standard Collect Feedback Workflow within Sharepoint which is set to trigger when a new file is added into a document library. When I add a new document, SharePoint sends an email to whoever uploaded the document telling them Tasks have been sent to the applicable users.

However, those emails are never sent nor received by users.  I have checked, and e-mail notification is turned on.

Comment: Are you getting emails from alerts? I question if the farm is configured correctly. Also, are you grabbing/assigning the email address properly in the workflow? Try hardcoding an email address and see if it sends.

Answer (score 1):

Have you configured [Incoming and Outgoing emails in SharePoint Server 2010](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pareshg/archive/2010/04/23/how-to-configure-incoming-and-outgoing-emails-in-sharepoint-server-2010.aspx)?, If not then configure it and then test the workflow.